# Header per source file

Tags: c, header

I'm trying to understand the purpose behind one header per each source file method. As I see it, headers are meant for sharing function declarations, `typedef`'s and macro's between several files that utilize them. When you make a header file for your `.c` file it has the disadvantage that each time you want to see a function declaration or macro you need to refer to the header file, and generally it is simpler that everything is in one source file (not the whole software, of course).

So why do programmers use this method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The header files in C separate declarations (which must be available to each .c file that uses the functions) from the definitions (which must be in one place).  Further, they provide a little modularity, since you can put only the public interface into a header file, and not mention functions and static variables that should be internal to the .c file.  That uses the file system to provide a public interface and private implementation.

The practice of one .h file to one .c file is mostly convenience.  That way, you know that the declarations are in the .h file, and the definitions in the corresponding .c file.

Comment: if I have declarations that need to be shared by several files, and they do not logically correspond one .c file? say, some #define's, that are used by most of the files. Isn't it better to create a header file with all of those? something neutral that doesn't associate with one .c file?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that each header contains a group of declarations that relate to each other. In most cases it fits that each .c file has a corresponding .h, but you can add extra .h files (e.g. to define global constants or enums). Ultimately, you're in charge of how you use headers to organise your code.

Comment: @JasonWilliams: Or extra .c files, whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yes (the OP was specifically asking about headers, hence the specific focus on .h)

Answer (score 9):

Logical, structured organisation and small source files enable:

- **faster, better programming**  - breaking the code into more manageable and understandable chunks makes it easier to find, understand and edit the relevant code.
- **code re-usability** - different "modules" of code can be separated into groups of source/header files that you can more easily integrate into different programs.
- **better "encapsulation"**  - only the .c files that specifically include that header can use the features from it, which helps you to minimise the relationships between different parts of your code, which aids modularity. It doesn't stop you using things from anywhere, but it helps you to think about why a particular c file needs to access functions declared in a particular header.
- **Aids teamwork** - two programmers trying to change the same code file concurrently usually cause problems (e.g. exclusive locks) or extra work (e.g. code merges) that slow each other down.
- **faster compiles** - if you have one header then every time you make a change in it you must recompile everything. With many small headers, only the .c files that #include the changed header must be rebuilt.
- **easier maintainability & refactoring** - for all the above reasons

In particular, "one header for each source file" makes it very easy to find the declarations relevant to the c file you are working in. As soon as you start to coalesce multiple headers into a single file, it starts to become difficult to relate the c and h files, and ultimately makes building a large application much more difficult. If you're only working on a small application then it's still a good idea to get into the habit of using a scalable approach.

Answer (score 6):

Programmers use this method because it **allows them to separate interface from implementation** while **guaranteeing that client code and implementation agree on the declarations of the functions**.  The .h file is the "single point of truth" (see Don't Repeat Yourself) about the prototype of each function.

(Client code is the code that `#include`'s the .h file in order to use the exported functions, but does not implement any of the functions in the .h.)

Answer (score 4):

Because, as you said yourself, it is not feasible to put the "whole software" into one source file.

If your program is very small, then yes it's is simpler just to put everything in one .c file. As your program gets larger, it becomes helpful to organize things by putting related functions together in different .c files. Further, in the .h files you can restrict the declarations you give to declarations of things that are *supposed* to be used by things in other .c files.  If a .c file doesn't contain anything that should be accessible outside itself, it needs no header.

For example, if .c has function foo() and fooHelper(), but nobody except foo() is supposed to call fooHelper() directly, then by putting foo() and fooHelper() into foo.c, only putting the declaration of foo() in foo.h, and declaring fooHelper() as static, it helps to enforce that other parts of your program should only access foo() and should not know or care about fooHelper(). Kind of a non object-oriented form of encapsulation.

Finally, make engines are generally smart enough to rebuild only those files which have changed since the last build, so splitting into multiple .c files (using .h files to share what needs to be shared) helps speed up builds.

Answer (score 4):

You only put in your header file the bare minimum that other source files need to "see" in order to compile. I've seen some people that put everything non-code into the header file (all typedefs, all #define's, all structures, etc.) even if nothing else in the codebase will be using those. That makes the header file much harder to read for yourself and those who want to use your module.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need one header per source file. One header per module, containing the public interface, and maybe an additional header containing private declarations etc shared between files in that module.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a header for a source file method means that you declare only the functions from that compilation unit in that header.

That way you don't pollute with declarations you don't need. (in large software project might be a problem)

As for separate compilation units, these speed up the compilation and can help you avoid collisions if private symbols are declared static.