# What is a C header file?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the point of header files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184646/what-are-the-point-of-header-files-in-c)

Hi,

What is a C header file?
Is there an alternative just to include more c code?