# Why declaration of a pre defined function and code of that pre defined function are in different files?

Tags: c

Suppose we consider math library functions in c language . declaration's are in header file #include whereas code is in math library (which we link during compilation by -lm) . Why both declaration and code are not in same file ?
I am  a beginner .

Comment: No it is different question !!!!!!

Comment: Ok, so try this instead: [What are the point of header files in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184646/what-are-the-point-of-header-files-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)