# Raylib Easing Functions Header Implementation

Tags: raylib

I'm a newbie coder and decided on using raylib to learn c / c#.. I saw an example with reasings.h header file and wanted to run that example on my local machine. I installed raylib via https://github.com/raylib-extras/game-premake

Everything worked perfectly and the raylib game runs, however I'm not sure how to use readings.h in the include sections because it says file not found, was curious how I could use this header?

Also I do see the reasings.h in my C drive C:\Users\Hoyos\Desktop\m_c_t\RAYLIB_proj1\raylib-master\examples\shapes.

Any help would be appreciated. ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Just put the reasings.h in the same folder as your shapes_easings_ball_anim.c file (I suspect you are using this example).

Here you can find a longer answer: [Reading the header of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191269/reading-the-header-of-a-file)