# error C3861: 'ls_file': identifier not found

Tags: c

I am learning to write my own Virtual File system but besides the logical error in program something other than that keeps coming i checked all the declarations within the program  but couldn't figure it out.

helper function

```
#include "header.h"

UFDT UFDTArr[50];
SUPERBLOCK SUPERBLOCKobj;
PINODE head=NULL;

void man(char *name)
{
    if(name==NULL) return;

    if(_stricmp(name,"ls")==0)
    {
        printf("Description : Used to list all information of file\n");
        printf("Usage : ls\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("ERROR : No manual entry available\n");
    }
}
    void DisplayHelp()
{
    printf("ls : To List Out all files \n");
    printf("clear : To Clear consol\n");
}

void CreateDILB()
{
    PINODE newn=NULL;
    PINODE temp=head;
    int i=1;

    while(i<=MAXINODE)
    {
        newn=(PINODE)malloc(sizeof(INODE));
        newn->LinkCount=newn->ReferenceCount=0;
        newn->FileType=newn->FileSize=0;
        newn->Buffer=NULL;
        newn->next=NULL;
        newn->InodeNumber=i;

        if(temp==NULL)
        {
            head=newn;
            temp=head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next=newn;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        i++;
    }

}

void InitialiseSuperBlock()
{
    int i=0;
    while(i<50)
    {
        UFDTArr[i].ptrfiletable=NULL;
        i++;
    }

    SUPERBLOCKobj.TotalInodes=MAXINODE;
    SUPERBLOCKobj.FreeInode=MAXINODE;
}
void ls_file()
{
    PINODE temp=head;

    if(SUPERBLOCKobj.FreeInode== MAXINODE)
    {
        printf("Error : There are no files ");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n File Name\tInode Number\tFile Size\tLink count\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------");

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->FileType!=0)
        {
            printf("%s\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n");
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

main file

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    char *ptr=NULL;
    int ret=0,fd=0,count=0;
    char command[4][80],str[80],arr[1024];

    InitialiseSuperBlock();
    CreateDILB();

    while(1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        strcpy_s(str,"");

        printf("Sachin VFS :> ");
        fgets(str,80,stdin);

        count=sscanf(str,"%s%s%s %s",command[0],command[1],command[2],command[3]);

        if(count==1)
        {
            if(_stricmp(command[0],"ls")==0)
            {
                ls_file();
            }

            else if(_stricmp(command[0],"clear")==0)
            {
                system("cls");
                continue;
            }
        else
        {
            printf("\n ERROR : Command not found!!! \n");
            continue;
        }

    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

header file

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAXINODE 50
#define READ 1
#define WRITE 2
#define MAXFILESIZE 1024
#define REGULAR 1
#define SPECIAL 2
#define START 0
#define CURRENT 1
#define END 2

#include<iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<io.h>

typedef struct superblock
{
    int TotalInodes;
    int FreeInode;

}SUPERBLOCK,*PSUPERBLOCK;

typedef struct inode
{
    char FileName[50];
    int InodeNumber;
    int FileSize;
    int FileActualSize;
    int FileType;
    char *Buffer;
    int LinkCount;
    int ReferenceCount;
    int permission;
    struct inode *next;

}INODE,*PINODE,**PPINODE;

typedef struct filetable
{
    int readoffset;
    int writeoffset;
    int count;
    int mode;
    PINODE ptrinode;

}FILETABLE,*PFILETABLE;

typedef struct ufdt
{
    PFILETABLE ptrfiletable;

}UFDT;
```

the one solution to this problem i got is declaring all the functions in main file above main to make compiler identify the functions but i still couldn't figure it out why it cant identify the same functions when i declare them in other file?

the default functions are working like `system("cls");` but my functions are not working

could anyone help me to understand the reason of this error and possible solution ?

P.S.- I have pasted small part of my code the actual code is too long to post if anyone wants me to post it i will in comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief - you should declare `ls_file()` in your `header.h`:

```
void ls_file();
```

This is a common technique to export some objects / functions outside of file where they are defined. Both "implementation" and "client" `*.c` files must include that header. The former one - in order to guarantee consistency of actual definitions and publicly-visible declarations, the latter one - to provide client code with proper and explicit declarations.

> ... still couldn't figure it out why it cant identify the same
>   functions when i declare them in other file?

In general compiler should see declarations or definitions of functions / globals before any referencing to them. This is because during compilation process translator works only with one `.c` source, and knows nothing about another source files and their content.

P.S [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1168011/2878070) may enlighten you a bit more.